# Learning F# - printing prime numbers

Tags: algorithm, f#, primes

Yesterday I started looking at F# during some spare time. I thought I would start with the standard problem of printing out all the prime numbers up to 100. Heres what I came up with...

```
#light
open System

let mutable divisable = false
let mutable j = 2

for i = 2 to 100 do
    j <- 2
    while j < i do
        if i % j = 0 then divisable <- true
        j <- j + 1

    if divisable = false then Console.WriteLine(i)
    divisable <- false
```

The thing is I feel like I have approached this from a C/C# perspective and not embraced the true functional language aspect.

I was wondering what other people could come up with - and whether anyone has any tips/pointers/suggestions. I feel good F# content is hard to come by on the web at the moment, and the last functional language I touched was [HOPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hope_(programming_language)) about 5 years ago in university.

Comment: As a side note, it's very much out of the spirit of F# to use `Console.WriteLine`. I would suggest using `printfn "%i" i` instead.

Comment: printf is more typesafe and can infer some types.

Comment: Try rewriting it using a fold.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple implementation of the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) in F#:

```
let rec sieve = function
    | (p::xs) -> p :: sieve [ for x in xs do if x % p > 0 then yield x ]
    | []      -> []

let primes = sieve [2..50]
printfn "%A" primes  // [2; 3; 5; 7; 11; 13; 17; 19; 23; 29; 31; 37; 41; 43; 47]
```

This implementation won't work for very large lists but it illustrates the elegance of a functional solution.

Comment: Nice, but I think that "List.filter (fun x -> x % p > 0) xs" would be more idiomatic than the explicit list comprehension.

Comment: Keep in mind that that's not a real sieve. That algorithm is very slow (bad asymptotic complexity compared to the real sieve).

Comment: Let me explain the difference. The Sieve of Eratosthenes only marks off multiples of the current prime number (`p` in your code). So this is # of multiples of the current prime number steps. Your code however performs a divisibility test for all remaining numbers, not just the multiples. As the numbers get large there are far more non-multiples than multiples, so your algorithm does a lot of extra work compared to the real sieve.

Comment: The idea comes from this awesome paper:  http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the info, very interesting! This code was just a port of the Haskell example found on the above link.

Answer (score 3):

Using a Sieve function like [Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is a good way to go.  Functional languages work really well with lists, so I would start with that in mind for struture.

On another note, functional languages work well constructed out of functions (heh).  For a functional language "feel" I would build a Sieve function and then call it to print out the primes.  You could even split it up--one function builds the list and does all the work and one goes through and does all the printing, neatly separating functionality.

There's a couple of interesting versions [here](http://stepheneasey.wordpress.com/2009/03/13/generating-primes-in-f/).
And there are well known implementations in other similar languages.  [Here's one](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.ai.genetic/msg/0e6338ae12f1f653?pli=1) in OCAML that  beats one in C.

Answer (score 3):

Here are my two cents:

```
let rec primes = 
  seq { 
    yield 2
    yield! (Seq.unfold (fun i -> Some(i, i + 2)) 3) 
           |> Seq.filter (fun p -> 
                primes
                |> Seq.takeWhile (fun i -> i * i <= p)
                |> Seq.forall (fun i -> p % i <> 0))
  }
  for i in primes do
    printf "%d " i
```

Or maybe this clearer version of the same thing as `isprime` is defined as a separate function:

```
let rec isprime x =
    primes
    |> Seq.takeWhile (fun i -> i*i <= x)
    |> Seq.forall (fun i -> x%i <> 0)

and primes = 
    seq {
        yield 2
        yield! (Seq.unfold (fun i -> Some(i,i+2)) 3)
                |> Seq.filter isprime
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You definitely do not want to learn from this example, but I wrote an F# implementation of [a NewSqueak sieve](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=810232012617965344) based on message passing:

```
type 'a seqMsg =   
    | Die   
    | Next of AsyncReplyChannel<'a>   

type primes() =   
    let counter(init) =   
        MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->   
            let rec loop n =   
                async { let! msg = inbox.Receive()   
                        match msg with   
                        | Die -> return ()   
                        | Next(reply) ->   
                            reply.Reply(n)   
                            return! loop(n + 1) }   
            loop init)   

    let filter(c : MailboxProcessor<'a seqMsg>, pred) =   
        MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->   
            let rec loop() =   
                async {   
                    let! msg = inbox.Receive()   
                    match msg with   
                    | Die ->   
                        c.Post(Die)   
                        return()   
                    | Next(reply) ->   
                        let rec filter' n =   
                            if pred n then async { return n }   
                            else  
                                async {let! m = c.AsyncPostAndReply(Next)   
                                       return! filter' m }   
                        let! testItem = c.AsyncPostAndReply(Next)   
                        let! filteredItem = filter' testItem   
                        reply.Reply(filteredItem)   
                        return! loop()   
                }   
            loop()   
        )   

    let processor = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->   
        let rec loop (oldFilter : MailboxProcessor<int seqMsg>) prime =   
            async {   
                let! msg = inbox.Receive()   
                match msg with   
                | Die ->   
                    oldFilter.Post(Die)   
                    return()   
                | Next(reply) ->   
                    reply.Reply(prime)   
                    let newFilter = filter(oldFilter, (fun x -> x % prime <> 0))   
                    let! newPrime = oldFilter.AsyncPostAndReply(Next)   
                    return! loop newFilter newPrime   
            }   
        loop (counter(3)) 2)   

    member this.Next() = processor.PostAndReply( (fun reply -> Next(reply)), timeout = 2000)

    interface System.IDisposable with
        member this.Dispose() = processor.Post(Die)

    static member upto max =   
        [ use p = new primes()
          let lastPrime = ref (p.Next())
          while !lastPrime <= max do
            yield !lastPrime
            lastPrime := p.Next() ]
```

Does it work?

```
> let p = new primes();;

val p : primes

> p.Next();;
val it : int = 2
> p.Next();;
val it : int = 3
> p.Next();;
val it : int = 5
> p.Next();;
val it : int = 7
> p.Next();;
val it : int = 11
> p.Next();;
val it : int = 13
> p.Next();;
val it : int = 17
> primes.upto 100;;
val it : int list
= [2; 3; 5; 7; 11; 13; 17; 19; 23; 29; 31; 37; 41; 43; 47; 53; 59; 61; 67; 71;
   73; 79; 83; 89; 97]
```

Sweet! :)

Comment: Easy bit of code there for someone who has been doing it a day :). Probably pass on your example, but thanks lol...

Answer (score 1):

Simple but inefficient suggestion:

- Create a function to test whether a single number is prime
- Create a list for numbers from 2 to 100
- Filter the list by the function
- Compose the result with another function to print out the results

To make this efficient you really want to test for a number being prime by checking whether or not it's divisible by any lower primes, which will require memoisation. Probably best to wait until you've got the simple version working first :)

Let me know if that's not enough of a hint and I'll come up with a full example - thought it may not be until tonight...

Comment: I would implement that using the Sieve of Eratosthenes ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes ). I can imagine that to be quite usable for a functional approach (though I don't know anything at all about F#)

Answer (score 1):

Here is [my old post at HubFS](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/4138.aspx) about using recursive seq's to implement prime number generator.

For case you want fast implementation, there is [nice OCaml code by Markus Mottl](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/ml-archives/caml-list/2002/07/1bcb179aadddedca9812baa7f17d6403.en.html)

P.S. if you want to iterate prime number up to 10^20 you really want to port primegen by D. J. Bernstein to F#/OCaml :)

Answer (score 1):

While solving the same problem, I have implemented [Sieve of Atkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) in F#. It is one of the most efficient modern algorithms.

```
// Create sieve
let initSieve topCandidate =
    let result = Array.zeroCreate<bool> (topCandidate + 1)
    Array.set result 2 true
    Array.set result 3 true
    Array.set result 5 true
    result
// Remove squares of primes
let removeSquares sieve topCandidate =
    let squares =
        seq { 7 .. topCandidate}
            |> Seq.filter (fun n -> Array.get sieve n)
            |> Seq.map (fun n -> n * n)
            |> Seq.takeWhile (fun n -> n <= topCandidate)
    for n2 in squares do
        n2
            |> Seq.unfold (fun state -> Some(state, state + n2))
            |> Seq.takeWhile (fun x -> x <= topCandidate)
            |> Seq.iter (fun x -> Array.set sieve x false)
    sieve

// Pick the primes and return as an Array
let pickPrimes sieve =
    sieve
        |> Array.mapi (fun i t -> if t then Some i else None)
        |> Array.choose (fun t -> t)
// Flip solutions of the first equation
let doFirst sieve topCandidate =
    let set1 = Set.ofList [1; 13; 17; 29; 37; 41; 49; 53]
    let mutable x = 1
    let mutable y = 1
    let mutable go = true
    let mutable x2 = 4 * x * x
    while go do
        let n = x2 + y*y
        if n <= topCandidate then
            if Set.contains (n % 60) set1 then
                Array.get sieve n |> not |> Array.set sieve n

            y <- y + 2
        else
            y <- 1
            x <- x + 1
            x2 <- 4 * x * x
            if topCandidate < x2 + 1 then
                go <- false
// Flip solutions of the second equation
let doSecond sieve topCandidate =
    let set2 = Set.ofList [7; 19; 31; 43]
    let mutable x = 1
    let mutable y = 2
    let mutable go = true
    let mutable x2 = 3 * x * x
    while go do
        let n = x2 + y*y
        if n <= topCandidate then
            if Set.contains (n % 60) set2 then
                Array.get sieve n |> not |> Array.set sieve n

            y <- y + 2
        else
            y <- 2
            x <- x + 2
            x2 <- 3 * x * x
            if topCandidate < x2 + 4 then
                go <- false
// Flip solutions of the third equation
let doThird sieve topCandidate =
    let set3 = Set.ofList [11; 23; 47; 59]
    let mutable x = 2
    let mutable y = x - 1
    let mutable go = true
    let mutable x2 = 3 * x * x
    while go do
        let n = x2 - y*y
        if n <= topCandidate && 0 < y then
            if Set.contains (n % 60) set3 then
                Array.get sieve n |> not |> Array.set sieve n

            y <- y - 2
        else
            x <- x + 1
            y <- x - 1
            x2 <- 3 * x * x
            if topCandidate < x2 - y*y then
                go <- false

// Sieve of Atkin
let ListAtkin (topCandidate : int) =
    let sieve = initSieve topCandidate

    [async { doFirst sieve topCandidate }
     async { doSecond sieve topCandidate }
     async { doThird sieve topCandidate }]
        |> Async.Parallel
        |> Async.RunSynchronously
        |> ignore

    removeSquares sieve topCandidate |> pickPrimes
```

I know some don't recommend to use Parallel Async, but it did increase the speed ~20% on my 2 core (4 with hyperthreading) i5. Which is about the same increase I got using TPL.

I have tried rewriting it in functional way, getting read of loops and mutable variables, but performance degraded 3-4 times, so decided to keep this version.